# Listview Array Adapter position onClick

Tags: android, listview, position, adapter

I have a listview with an ArrayAdapter. The ListView at a position fills itselfs with the same position in some ArrayList. In each listitem
there are two buttons. When the onClickListener start, it gets
the position of the overrided View getView(position, View etc.), takes some variables out of the ArrayList and sends it to a database. The problem is, the position is not really accurate. Sometimes I get the position of a Listitem above the Listitem I want. Here is the code:

```
public class MemoAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    private final Activity context;
    ArrayList<String> commentarray;
    ArrayList<String> fromarray;
    ArrayList<String> datearray;
    ArrayList<String> ids;
    ArrayList<String> feedback;
    Dialog dialog;
    EditText feedbacktxt;
    String token;
    String website;

    public MemoAdapter(Activity context, ArrayList<String> commentArray,
            ArrayList<String> fromArray, ArrayList<String> dateArray,
            ArrayList<String> ids, ArrayList<String> feedback, String token,
            String website) {
        super(context, R.layout.memo_listitem, commentArray);
        this.context = context;
        this.commentarray = commentArray;
        this.fromarray = fromArray;
        this.datearray = dateArray;
        this.ids = ids;
        this.feedback = feedback;
        this.token = token;
        this.website = website;
    }
    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {

        return 0;
    }
    // static to save the reference to the outer class and to avoid access to
    // any members of the containing class
    static class ViewHolder {

        public TextView textView;
        public TextView textView2;
        public TextView textView3;
        public TextView textView4;
        // public ImageView reply;
        // public ImageView accept;
        public Button reply;
        public Button accept;
        public RelativeLayout r;
    }
    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        final ViewHolder holder;
        View rowView = convertView;

        if (rowView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
            rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.memo_listitem, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();

            holder.textView = (TextView) rowView
                    .findViewById(R.id.memodescription);
            holder.textView2 = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.memofrom);
            holder.textView3 = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.memodate);
            holder.textView4 = (TextView) rowView
                    .findViewById(R.id.memofeedback);
            holder.reply = (Button) rowView.findViewById(R.id.buttonFeedback);
            holder.accept = (Button) rowView.findViewById(R.id.buttonAccepteer);
            rowView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) rowView.getTag();
        }

        holder.textView.setText(commentarray.get(position));
        holder.textView2.setText(datearray.get(position));
        holder.textView3.setText(fromarray.get(position));
        holder.textView4.setText(feedback.get(position));

        if (holder.textView4.getText().toString().equals("")
                || holder.textView4.getText().toString().equals(" ")) {
            holder.textView4.setText(" - ");
        }

        // ONCLICKLISTENER FOR REPLYIMAGE
        holder.reply.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dialog = new Dialog(NostradamusActivity2.parentcontext);
                dialog.setContentView(R.layout.memo_dialog);
                dialog.setTitle("Feedback");
                feedbacktxt = (EditText) dialog.findViewById(R.id.memoeddittxt);

                Button cancel = (Button) dialog
                        .findViewById(R.id.memobtncancel);

                // CANCEL BUTTON ONCLICKLISTENER REPLYIMAGE
                cancel.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });

                Button okay = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.memobtnokay);

                // OKAY BUTTON ONCLICKLISTENER REPLYIMAGE
                okay.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                    private String errormessage;
                    private AlertDialog alertDialog;

                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Database2 db = new Database2(
                                "https://"
                                        + website
                                        + "/index2.php?option=com_webservices&controller=json&method=core.memos.memo_feedback&token=",
                                "token", token, "id", ids.get(position),
                                "memo_feedback", feedbacktxt.getText()
                                        .toString());
         }

        // //ACCEPTEER MEMO BUTTON ONCLICKLISTENER
        holder.accept.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                        NostradamusActivity2.parentcontext);
                builder.setMessage("Heeft u de opdracht uitgevoerd?")
                        .setCancelable(false)
                        .setPositiveButton("Ja",
                                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    private AlertDialog alertDialog;

                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                            int id) {
                                        Database2 dbaccept = new Database2(
                                                "http://intern.koeckers.nl/index2.php?option=com_webservices&controller=json&method=core.memos.memo_state&token=",
                                                "token", token, "id", ids
                                                        .get(position),
                                                "memo_completed", "1");

                                                        dialog.dismiss();
                                            }
                                        } catch (Exception e) {
                                            e.printStackTrace();
                                        }
                                    }
                                })
                        .setNegativeButton("Nee",
                                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                            int id) {
                                        dialog.cancel();
                                    }
                                });
                AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
                alert.show();
            }
        });
        return rowView;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the item by `ids.get(position)`.
You are using the `arrayList`, instead use the `getTag()` method.
`rowView.getTag()` will give you the `ViewHolder` from which, you can get the correct ids and Feedback Text.

```
Database2 dbaccept = new Database2(
    "http://intern.koeckers.nl/index2.php? option=com_webservices&controller=json&method=core.memos.memo_state&token=",
    "token", token, "id", ids.get(position),
    "memo_completed", "1");
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I want to get the absolute position of the item. When I use your method rowView.getTag() I get back an object. What do I have to do with this. Convert to String and than to an Integer? I don't really understand..

Comment: Nope I took the question in the wrong way. rowView.getTag() will give u the viewHolder object, which will have the views that are in the row. I thought u r taking the values from the row. So what u can do is add an invisible textview(to the ViewHolder) where u can set the position and take it while u need. This is not the best way but till u get an answer u can use this workaround.